# Azure Container Apps- View trace logs in AppInsights

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

How do i get the application trace logs deployed in Azure Container Logs to view in Application Insights?

```
 _logger.LogInformation("get ratings " );
```

I have tried both Instrumentation key and ConnectionString to daprAI properties with no luck. I can view the logs in Logs Analytics (ContainerAppConsoleLogs_CL) so logs are working fine.

```
resource containerAppEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-03-01' = {
  name: containerAppEnvironmentName
  location: location
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    appLogsConfiguration: {
      destination: 'log-analytics'
      logAnalyticsConfiguration: {
        customerId: logAnalyticsWs.properties.customerId
        sharedKey: logAnalyticsWs.listKeys().primarySharedKey
      }
    }
    daprAIConnectionString: appInsights.properties.ConnectionString
    daprAIInstrumentationKey: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
    vnetConfiguration:  null
    zoneRedundant: false
  }
}
```

Have added the env values in the container apps container

```
 { name: 'ApplicationInsights__ConnectionString'
    value: appInsights.properties.ConnectionString
  }
  {
    name: 'ApplicationInsights__InstrumentationKey'
    value: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
  }
```

bootstrapped in the program files

```
 builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

Logs are not visible in the appinsights
[image]

Comment: By default any trace with a severity of Information is ignored, only Warning and up is logged.

Comment: And please, post code as formatted text, **not** as images.

Comment: @PeterBons : Updated to use formatted text as suggested. All severity logs are visible in appinsights when code is deployed to Azure App Service.  I don't see why this can't be visible when deployed to Azure Container Apps?

Comment: @PeterBons : I tested and noticed only warnings are visible in the appinsights, how to override this default behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got logs ingestion in appinsights for ACA working by updating 1. appsetting file and 2. Using the sdk for in the program.cs file.

Program.cs

```
var appInsights = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights");
ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions telemetryOptions=new()
{
ConnectionString=appInsights.GetValue<string>("ConnectionString"),
EnableDebugLogger=true
};
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(telemetryOptions);
```

appsettings.json

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": ""
  }
}
```